# Why does the Random class somtimes return nothing?

Tags: c#, console-application

As you can see in my code down below, I have A and B. For example if I place the result at B then it sometimes return as result=0, nothing prints out in the console. But A works as it is expected to do. I don't really understand it, I did put a breakpoint, and stepped into the code but it didn't tell me much, just that the result return 0, this should infact print out the movie at Index 0? Sorry for being stupid, just want some clarification.

```
 private static void PickRandomMovie(List<Movie> movie)
    {
        var rng = new Random();

        //A:
        var result = rng.Next(0, movie.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < movie.Count; i++)
        {
            //B:
            //var result = rng.Next(0, movie.Count);

            if (movie[i].Index.Equals(result))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(movie[i].Title);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<Movie> AddMovie()
    {
        return new List<Movie>
        {
           new Movie(new Movie(0, "Shark Attack", "Horror, Thriller")),
           new Movie(new Movie(1, "Tom Clancy's", "Action")),
           new Movie(new Movie(2, "American Pie", "Comedy")),
           new Movie(new Movie(3, "Ted", "Comedy")),
           new Movie(new Movie(4, "Ted 2", "Comedy")),
           new Movie(new Movie(5, "American Pie 2", "Comedy")),
           new Movie(new Movie(6, "Tom Clancy's 2", "Action")),
           new Movie(new Movie(7, "Guardians of the Galaxy", "Comedy, Action")),

        };
    }
```

Comment: As an aside, your code first of all should not compile (you're nesting `Movie` instances) and second, if you're just going to be indexing movies by order added you may as well directly use `movie[result]`, there is no added value in keeping the indexes separately -- doubly so if you're going to enumerate all the elements looking for it. This is assuming you don't need to keep an explicit index separately for reordering purposes, of course.

Comment: I saw that, I used the Visual studio tool to make the method. Fixed it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

`A` chooses a random number and then loops all items in your array looking for the one where `Index` matches your pre-selected random number

`B` loops the array of items picking a new random number *on every iteration of the loop* and only writes the result if it happens to match.

There is a fairly high chance that the `B` case will never hit a match

Comment: Well.. that explained it all. Hehe. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

While Jamiec explains the error well enough, I would suggest a few changes to your method:

1. Remove the explicit index from the movie objects, objects might have an *id*, but should not know or care about how they are stored or what index they have.
2. Don't loop thru the list, just do the indexing explicitly.
3. You should probably separate the search of the random item, from the print to the console part. That will help make your functions reusable.
4. There is no reason not to make such a function generic.

```
public static T PickRandomValue<T>(List<T> values, Random rng )
    => values[rng.Next(values.Count)];
...
var rng = new Random();
Console.WriteLine(PickRandomValue(movies, rng).Title);
```

Comment: Thank you! The generic method is looking good.  I will keep this in mind.

Comment: I know this is a dumb question, but could you explain some more about the "indexing explicitly" - is it about performance or just because I'm searching for an index already?

Comment: @hexaN98 it is both much faster and easier to read to use `values[i]` than a loop that have to check every item in the list/array. Anytime I see code like your example I have to try to figure out if there is some special reason the code is written like it is, or if the author just did not know any better.

Comment: @hexaN98 Since you are storing the index inside the objects you are also creating the possibility of errors, all that is needed is that you forget to update a number when pasting another movie, or update all the other indexes when removing a movie. My example will only fail if the list is empty.